# Java regex for consecutive exponential terms

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I've tested this regex:

```
String regex = "[e][#](.)+[$]
```

the regex works well to identify exponential terms, however it breaks when there are two or more consecutive exponential terms.

I test the regex with the usual code:

```
while(matcher.find()){
String string = matcher.group();
System.out.println("this one: "+string);
}
```

When I type the expression:

```
e#x$ + 3e#x+1$
```

string equals to  **(e#(x$+3e#x+1$))**

By the way, I added the parentheses inside the while loop. They are necessary for
what I am trying to accomplish.

I want the result of string to be **(e(#x$))+3(e(#x+1$)**

**I know the problem lies in "(.)+ What I think is happening is that the regex
includes the first $, what I need is for it to stop at the first $.**

How can I include this logic inside the regex?

thank you

Comment: ..You mean `.+?`

Comment: no, the part of the regex (.)+  is causing to include the first $ @YCF_L

Comment: I don't get you @i_o can you please show us some input output examples?

Comment: Found the answer in the post :  Regex to first occurrence only. Thanks  just change (.)+ to (.*?)+ to make it un-greedy. Never knew there was so much greed. HAHA